# Check Related Events on Two Calendars

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get free dates on two calendars. Each calendar represents a person (Bob and Alice).  I have two objects of busy slot (from start to finish).  If a customer wants to book a service that lasts for example 100 minutes at 11:00 o’clock (20’ with Bob and 80’ with Alice), I have to check if Bob is available from 11:00 to 11:20 and Alice from 11:20 to 12:40. The sequence is always Bob and then Alice, with no space between them. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the code?

```
let min1 = 20; // the service engages Bob for 20 minutes (e.g. start at 10:00 to 10:20)
let min2 = 70; // the service engages Alice for 70 minutes (e.g. start at 10:20 to 11:30)

let serviceLength1 = min1 * 60 * 1000; // service length in ms
let serviceLength2 = min2 * 60 * 1000;

// events resp from server
let busy1 = [
 { start: "2021-05-25T09:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T09:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-25T12:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T13:15:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-25T16:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T16:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T09:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T09:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T11:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T11:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T15:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T15:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-27T09:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-27T09:45:00+02:00" },
];

let busy2 = [
 { start: "2021-05-25T09:45:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T10:00:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-25T11:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T11:45:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-25T14:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T14:40:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-25T16:45:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-25T17:00:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T09:45:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T10:00:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T11:45:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T12:00:00+02:00" },
 { start: "2021-05-26T13:00:00+02:00", end: "2021-05-26T13:35:00+02:00" },
];

let start1 = busy1.map((item) => Date.parse(item.start));
let end1 = busy1.map((item) => Date.parse(item.end));

let start2 = busy2.map((item) => Date.parse(item.start));
let end2 = busy2.map((item) => Date.parse(item.end));

let freeTime1 = [];
let freeTime2 = [];
let i = 0;
let ii = 0;

while (i < start1.length - 1) {
 if (start1[i + 1] - end1[i] >= serviceLength1) {
   freeTime1[i] = start1[i + 1] - end1[i];
 } else {
   freeTime1[i] = 0;
 }
 i = i + 1;
}

while (ii < start2.length - 1) {
 if (start2[ii + 1] - end2[ii] >= serviceLength2) {
   freeTime2[ii] = start2[ii + 1] - end2[ii];
 } else {
   freeTime2[ii] = 0;
 }
 ii = ii + 1;
}

let result1 = {};
let result2 = {};

end1.forEach((key, i) => {
 result1[key] = freeTime1[i];
 if (result1[key] < serviceLength1) delete result1[key];
});

end2.forEach((key, i) => {
 result2[key] = freeTime2[i];
 if (result2[key] < serviceLength2) delete result2[key];
});

let arr1 = {};
arr1 = Object.keys(result1);

let arr2 = {};
arr2 = Object.keys(result2);

let freeSlot = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
 for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
     if (arr2[j] - arr1[i] == serviceLength1) // ?
   {
     freeSlot[i] = arr1[i]; // array of service-start date (with Bob that will end with Alice)
   }
 }
}

// let free = freeSlot.map((item) => new Date(freeSlot));
```

[image: Calendar Screenshot]

Comment: I think you could simplify the logic a lot if you create "free time objects" like `{ start, end, duration }`, then sort them by start date. Then iterate over the free times of Bob, and keep an index for Alice. For every free time of Bob, increase the Alice index until `bob[i].start <= alice[j].start` Then check if `alice[j].end - bob[i].start > min` (that would be kind of a "merge join" which is way more efficient than a double for loop)